# CSS line hieght pulls wrapper up or down depending on number of lines inside a wrapper

Tags: html, css

I am having a CSS issue when it comes to text wrapping, I have created a large anchor tag buttons to manage sections of the web app.

[image]

This is how my page buttons look now, I am trying to align them to the top.

I have tried few different ways to wrap up the content to accommodate this however it was all FALE :(.

Here is my HTML & CSS:
I am open to wrapping them any way as long as it works.

```
<li>
                                <a href="#" class="manage-action-button">
                                    <span class="icon-wrap"><i class="fas fa-users fa-3x"></i></span>
                                    <span class="text-wrap">Manage People</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="manage-action-button">
                                    <span class="icon-wrap">
                                        <i class="fas fa-suitcase fa-3x"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="text-wrap">
                                        Manage Projects
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="manage-action-button">
                                    <span class="icon-wrap">
                                        <i class="fas fa-key fa-3x"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="text-wrap">
                                        Manage User Permissions
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 150px !important;

        li {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 150px !important;
        }
    }

    .manage-action-button {
        display: block;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background: #156c92;
        margin: 0 20px 0 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;

        .icon-wrap {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            svg {
                font-size: 38px;
                display: block;
                margin: 30px auto 0;
            }
        }

        &:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
        }
    }

    .single-line {
        margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    }
```

Comment: `vertical-align: top` to `li`

Comment: OMG>>>> @fcalderan hahah I lost like 45 min on this ;) hahah thanks

Comment: @fcalderan I feel ashamed